# Finding acceleration of wedge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, free-body-diagram

Consider a situation in which there is an object placed above a triangular wedge with angle $\theta$ as shown. The situation is ideal with no friction, etc.

[image: Mass sliding down inclined plane]

We've to find acceleration of the wedge.

### My Working

During the entire course of motion, the block remains attached to the wedge, therefore it applies a normal force of $m_2 g \cos \theta$ on the wedge. Taking its horizontal component, we get $m_2g\cos\theta\sin\theta$. Therefore the acceleration should be:

$$
\frac{m_{2} g \cos\theta\sin\theta}{m_{1}}
$$

But that's **incorrect**.

Where did I go wrong? Furthermore my teacher uses the wedge frame to arrive at the actual answer. What's the rationale behind this approach?

Comment: The horizontal component of a normal force should be zero because the directions are perpendicular. Instead, start by drawing a free body diagram of the block.

Comment: I think OP is referring to the horizontal component of the normal force on the wedge by the block. Here horizontal is w.r.t ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where did I go wrong ?

When working out the normal force you implicitly assumed that the block is stationary.

> What's the rationale behind this approach (using the frame of reference of the wedge) ?

In the frame of reference of the wedge, the block moves down the wedge. So if the block's vertical and horizontal accelerations in the wedge frame are $a_v'$ and $a_h'$ we have

$\displaystyle \frac {a_v'}{a_h'} = \tan \theta$

Converting these accelerations to an inertial frame of reference, we have to add the wedge's horizontal acceleration $a_w$ to get

$\displaystyle \frac {a_v}{a_h + a_w} = \tan \theta$

where $a_v$, $a_h$ are the block's vertical and horizontal accelerations in the  inertial reference frame. So we have

$a_v \cos \theta = (a_h + a_w) \sin \theta$

If we introduce an unknown normal force $N$ then we can write down the horizontal and vertical equations of motion for the block and the horizontal equation of motion for the wedge. Together with the above equation, this gives us four equations in four unknown quantities ($a_v, a_h, a_w$ and $N$) and four known quantities ($m_1, m_2, \theta$ and $g$), which we can solve to find $a_w$ as a function of $m_1, m_2, \theta$ and $g$.

Comment: So, I assumed the normal force to be $mgcos \theta$ which is not true?? If that's the case, how would one know that?